# "View Test Results" is missing from TFS 2010 web access build summary?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm using vs\tfs 2010 to queue builds with tests. When using vs to queue the build, I can access the "View Test Results" in the build summary. But when I queue the build using the TFS web access, this link is missing from the build summary.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that opening test results requires Visual Studio or Test Manager.  Even so, I wouldn't see the harm in allowing you to download the file(s).  As a cheap work around you could click "View Log" and scroll down towards the bottom to see the test results.

Additionally, you could create a custom build control to display a hyperlink to the build results:

- http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/27/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-8-Send-information-to-the-build-log.aspx
- http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/10/02/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-13-Get-control-over-the-Build-Output.aspx